# SQL - Comment System with Revision History

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have two tables that I use for storing comments on a MySQL database.

The first stores the comment id, who's page it is posted on, who wrote the comment, and if it is a reply to another comment (respectively below).

```
Comments
---------------------------------
CommentId    BIGINT      PK,NN,AI
OwnerId      BIGINT      
AuthorId     BIGINT      
ParentId     BIGINT      
Created      TIMESTAMP
```

The second stores the content of the comment.

```
CommentsContent
----------------------------------
ContentId    BIGINT      PK,NN,AI
CommentId    BIGINT      
Content      TEXT        
Created      TIMESTAMP
```

So, let's say `Comments` has the following records:

```
CommentId  OwnerId  AuthorId  ParentId  Created
-----------------------------------------------------------
        1        1         2         0  2013-01-31 01:23:45
        2        1         2         0  2013-01-31 01:23:45
```

and `CommentsContent` has the following records, showing the edit history of the comment:

```
ContentId  CommentId  Content           Created
-----------------------------------------------------------
        1          1  Testing           2013-01-31 01:23:45
        2          2  Another test      2013-01-31 01:23:45
        3          1  Testing1          2013-01-31 01:23:46
        4          1  Testing123        2013-01-31 01:23:47
```

Now, I want to get the latest comment, along with it's last update date (which is the `Created` column in `CommentsContent`).

I tried:

```
SELECT
    c.CommentId,
    c.AuthorId,
    c.ParentId,
    c.Created,
    cc.Created as Updated,
    cc.Content
FROM
    Comments as c
JOIN
    CommentsContent as cc
ON
    cc.CommentId = c.CommentId
WHERE
    c.OwnerId = 1
```

Unfortunately, that returns all the rows in `CommentsContent` with their `Comments` data prepended.

I'm looking for the following output:

```
 CommentId  AuthorId  ParentId  Created              Updated              Content
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1         2         0  2013-01-31 01:23:45  2013-01-31 01:23:47  Testing123
         2         2         0  2013-01-31 01:23:45  2013-01-31 01:23:45  Another test
```

Is this possible in a single query without embedding a nested `SELECT`. Do I need to use a `GROUP` clause? I've heard that `GROUP` clauses have poor performance, though. Should I create some extra indexes to help speed up a `GROUP` clause?

Thanks for the input!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a nested select?

Comment: I have also heard nested selects are slow, but maybe I heard wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have windowing functions like SQL Server and some others.  So you will need to use a subquery for this:

```
SELECT
    c.CommentId,
    c.AuthorId,
    c.ParentId,
    c.Created,
    cc.Created as Updated,
    cc.Content
FROM Comments as c
JOIN CommentsContent as cc
  ON cc.CommentId = c.CommentId
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(created) MaxDate, commentid
  from CommentsContent
  group by commentid
) cc2
  on cc.created = cc2.maxdate
  and cc.commentid = cc2.commentid
WHERE c.OwnerId = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be926/9)

Comment: This is strange because in the demo, I see it returning only the 2 records that I wish, but locally, I'm getting all records returned.

Comment: I figured out why. I had a few comments with edits that had the same timestamp, so I changed it to use ContentId instead of Created date. All seems to be working now. Thank you.